# Sync Pi with local directory

Tags: ssh, unison

I have setup a Pi with ArchLinux. Now I want to sync one directory called Pi on my local machine with the directory Pi on my Pi.

At first I have written a little script that uses `rsync` but I've run into some problems as it is not bi-directional and couldn't create a parent directory.

Then I saw a post that mentioned `unison`. At this time I have this command:

```
unison /home/user/Pi/ ssh://ente@192.123.145.78:22//home/ente/Pi/
```

This works quite nicely. But I always have to type in my password and then what I want to. How can I make `unison` authenticate me with my RSA key I have generated for `ssh`?

I login via `ssh` with that key and `rsync` also did it. And how can I skip Unison's question what it should do?

```
unison /home/user/Cloud/Encrypted/ \
    ssh://ente@192.168.178.21:22//home/ente/Cloud << EOF
MYPASSW
g
EOF
```

Is probably not such a good idea?

Comment: A simpler approach is to use [Syncthing](http://syncthing.net/). There is an ARMv6 PKGBUILD in the AUR...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way as you would setup a password-less ssh connection.

From the machine you're starting `unison`:

```
 $ cd ~/.ssh
 $ ssh-keygen
```

Do not set a password for the key itself when issuing `ssh-keygen`. Otherwise you'll be asked for it.
Now copy the key to the other machine

```
 scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ente@192.168.178.21:/home/ente/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

or

```
 ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ente@192.168.178.21
```

Also, you could use `sshfs` to mount directory.

If you named your key differently, you need to tell `unison` about it:

```
  unison -sshargs="-i ~/.ssh/me"  [other unison options]
```

Comment: I have done this already but I have choosen another name, how can I tell unison which identifier file to choose? I have named my key me, so 'me' and 'me.pub'.

Comment: you can use `config` file from `.ssh` directory:

    `Host 192.168.178.21

      ForwardX11 no

      ForwardX11Trusted no

      Port 22

      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/me`

Comment: sshargs is listed in the unison help menu as:"sshargs xxx       other arguments (if any) for remote shell command" but when using it I get the error "unison: unknown option `--sshargs'"

Comment: sorry, this was a typo on my side: use only a single dash, i.e. `-sshargs=-i ~/.ssh/me`

Comment: I now get this message:"Profile /home/user/.unison//home/user/.ssh/me.prf does not exist" I probably have to add this, but how and where?

Comment: weird. it seems to think that the path you're providing to ssh is a `unison` profile. Try to wrap this into quotes `-sshargs="-i ~/.ssh/me"`